# Custom Headers in Logic App With Outlook Connector

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I am using custom headers via the office js library here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.internetheaders?view=outlook-js-preview to pass meta data in the email headers.
I can see that the header is added but when it is received via the logic app, the custom headers have been removed.
Is this a known issue? Is there a way to prevent the stripping of custom headers?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The outlook and sendgrid connector in logic app don't support custom header. So you could use logic app with Azure function, in the function forward email.

You can vote up this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/33461014-sendgrid-logic-apps-connector-add-support-for-cus) to promote the feature to be achieved as soon as possible.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not sure how forwarding the email will help. I am wanting to pass hidden data in an email. The user selects an option from an outlook add-in which adds a BCC email address. I also add some hidden data somehow (ideally in an x-header). Then my Logic app listens for new outlook emails arriving and forwards to an Azure function. The Functio  tries to get the hidden data out for processing but the x-header has been stripped out. Tried using a hidden html field too but that gets stripped out by Outlook desktop clients. At the moment I have ti show the hidden text in the email body.